# Trying to run Classic ASP application inside Docker, Install-WindowsFeature Web-ASP not working

Tags: docker, iis, asp-classic

Inside Dockerfile

```
# escape=`
FROM microsoft/iis
SHELL ["powershell", "-command"]
RUN Install-WindowsFeature Web-ASP
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY . .
```

Once I build I get the below error

> Step 3/5 : RUN Install-WindowsFeature Web-ASP  ---> Running in
>   f1b57ea65228 Install-WindowsFeature : The request to add or remove
>   features on the  specified server failed. Installation of one or more
>   roles, role services, or features failed. Error:  0x800f0922 At line:1
>   char:1
>   + Install-WindowsFeature Web-ASP
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (@{Vhd=; Credent...Name=localh     ost}:PSObject) [Install-WindowsFeature],
>   Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DISMAPI_Error__Failed_To_Enable_Updates,Microsof
>   t.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.AddWindowsFeatureCommand
>
> Success Restart Needed Exit Code      Feature Result
>   ------- -------------- ---------      --------------     False   No             Failed         {}
>
> The command 'powershell -command Install-WindowsFeature Web-ASP'
>   returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: Have you tried other tags of the iis container as a troubleshooting step?

I would try any of these:

    20200414-windowsservercore-1903,     20200414-windowsservercore-1909,     20200414-windowsservercore-ltsc2016,     20200414-windowsservercore-ltsc2019,     20200512-windowsservercore-1903,     20200512-windowsservercore-ltsc2016,     20200512-windowsservercore-ltsc2019

Comment: One of them worked, Thank you